# DnsDiscovery vs SeedPeers in bitcoinj

Tags: bitcoinj

First look in screenshot number one of davlik debug monitor server after running Bitcoin Wallet: http://piccy.info/view3/5090102/7074a1d99a96e67bdbea36a04073c21f/orig/
I suppose, that is normal work of Bitcoin Wallet.
Then I modified bitcoinj and bitcoin-wallet a little bit. I changed bitcoinj\core\src\main\java\com\google\bitcoin\kits\WalletAppKit.java (line 104):

```
vPeerGroup.addPeerDiscovery(new SeedPeers(params));
```

instead

```
vPeerGroup.addPeerDiscovery(new DnsDiscovery(params));
```

and bitcoin-wallet\wallet\src\de\schildbach\wallet\service\BlockchainServiceImpl.java (line 406):

```
private final PeerDiscovery normalPeerDiscovery = new SeedPeers(Constants.NETWORK_PARAMETERS);
```

instead

```
private final PeerDiscovery normalPeerDiscovery = new DnsDiscovery(Constants.NETWORK_PARAMETERS);
```

Look in screenshot number two of davlik debug monitor server after running Bitcoin Wallet to see the result: http://piccy.info/view3/5090104/aaf257fbd618863b16ed99ffb2263e66/orig/
I think, that is not normal work of app because you can see only "Peer died" and "Connection timed out".

So my question is: does class SeedPeers work correct? Maybe, it is not fully implemented?

P.S. Nonetheless, it could still work correct. I just don't have an opportunity to send or receive bitcoins to test Bitcoin Wallet with "SeedPeers" class instead "DnsDiscovery" class. So if you can do that, please do.

P.S.S. I'm not sure it is bitcoinj or Bitcoin Wallet problem.